# Simplifying Exponential Numbers Help?

Tags: linear-algebra

If you simplify $3\cdot3^{2x}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot4^{2x}\cdot25\cdot5^{3x}=6\cdot2^{2x}\cdot3^{2x}\cdot5^{2x}$, this can be written as $4^x\cdot5^x = \frac{a}{b}$. How do you express  $\frac{a}{b}$ in simplest form?

I did the math and first turned the whole equation into an exponential format:
$3^{2x+1}\cdot4^{2x-1}\cdot5^{3x+2}=(2\cdot3)\cdot2^{2x}\cdot3^{2x}\cdot5^{2x}$
$3^{2x+1}\cdot4^{2x-1}\cdot5^{3x+2}=2^{2x+1}\cdot3^{2x+1}\cdot5^{2x}$
$3^{2x+1}\cdot4^{2x-1}\cdot\frac{5^{3x+2}}{5^{2x}}=2^{2x+1}\cdot3^{2x+1}\cdot$
$3^{2x+1}\cdot4^{2x-1}\cdot5^{x+2}=2^{2x+1}\cdot3^{2x+1}\cdot$
$4^{2x-1}\cdot5^{x+2}=2^{2x+1}\cdot\frac{3^{2x+1}}{3^{2x+1}}$
$4^{2x-1}\cdot5^{x+2}=2^{2x+1}$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: You are almost there: from the last line you can say $4^{x} \cdot 5^{x}=8/25$. All you need is to write $2^{2x+1}=4^{x} \cdot 2$ and then simplify so that only $4^x 5^x$ remains on the left.

Answer (score 1):

$4^{2x-1} = 4^x\cdot4^{x-1}, 5^{x+2} = 25\cdot5^x $, hence

$$4^{2x-1}\cdot5^{x+2}=2^{2x+1} \iff\\
4^x\cdot4^{x-1}\cdot25\cdot5^x = 2^{2x+1}\iff\\
4^x\cdot(2^2)^{x-1}\cdot25\cdot5^x = 2^{2x+1} $$

Can you take it from here?

Recall the exponent rule $(a^b)^c = a^{bc} $:

$$4^x\cdot(2^2)^{x-1}\cdot25\cdot5^x = 2^{2x+1}\iff\\
4^x\cdot 2^{2x-2}\cdot25\cdot5^x = 2^{2x+1}\iff\\
4^x\cdot5^x = \frac{2^{2x+1}}{25\cdot2^{2x-2}}\iff\\
4^x\cdot5^x = \frac{2^{2x-2}\cdot2^3}{25\cdot2^{2x-2}}\iff\\
4^x\cdot5^x = \frac{8}{25} $$

Comment: Ok the answer is 8/25 and I see where the denominator, 25, comes from but I'm still confused on how to get the numerator, 8. @RSerrao

Comment: @Axop51 I edited my answer. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $4=2^2$, so $4^p=2^{2p}$.